# How calcutale GraphicsStream Position of specific pixel on screen?

Tags: c#, directx

How calculate position of specific pixel inside of graphics stream? This stream is screenshot of my primary monitor.
Lets say I want position for pixel at:

```
0, 0  
0, 10  
10, 0  
10, 10
```

Im using DirectX 9 SDK.
Here is part of code what Im using(from [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/274461/Very-fast-screen-capture-using-DirectX-in-Csharp) tutorial) to calculate position:

```
const int Bpp = 4;
int o = 20;
int m = 8;
int screenWidthMinusM = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width - m;
int screenHeightMinusM = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height - m;
int bx = (screenWidthMinusM - m) / 3 + m;
int by = (screenHeightMinusM - m) / 3 + m;
int bx2 = (screenWidthMinusM - m) * 2 / 3 + m;
int by2 = (screenHeightMinusM - m) * 2 / 3 + m;

long x, y;
long pos;

y = m;
for (x = m; x < screenWidthMinusM; x += o)
{
   pos = (y * Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width + x) * Bpp;  
   if (x < bx) tlPos.Add(pos);
   else if (x > bx && x < bx2) tPos.Add(pos);
   else if (x > bx2) trPos.Add(pos);
}
```

but this returns collection with numbers starting about 53 000 to about 7 000 000(from another similar method). After that color is extracted

```
Surface s = sc.CaptureScreen();
GraphicsStream gs = s.LockRectangle(LockFlags.None);

byte[] bu = new byte[4];    
foreach (long pos in positions)
{
    gs.Position = pos;
    gs.Read(bu, 0, 4);
    r += bu[2];
    g += bu[1];
    b += bu[0];
    i++;
}
```

I need to make my own collection containing these positions.

Comment: I may make a mistake (don't know what's a `GraphicsStream`), but it depends on the Vertex Shader used and the `World`, `View`, `Projection` matrices. Could you specify what version of DirectX and DirectX wrapper do you use?

Comment: DX9 and question was updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're having all pixels of your screenshot in this graphics stream ([doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.directx.graphicsstream_methods%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) and want to get the index within the stream of a specified pixelposition (x,y).

Therefore it should be easily: `Index = (x + y * screenwidth) * SizeOf(Pixel)`

For reading the data you should combine `Seek` with `Read`.

Comment: Em, no :) Assuming your screenwidth is 1920, (0,10) would lead to 19200 and (10,0) to 10.

Comment: one last question, is the screen 1920x1080 has last point at 1919x1079? And why 1920x1079 is without exception, but 1920x1080 returns exception "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."?

Comment: Hmm I think you're reading memory there which isn't allocated, but not all memory is protected. So it might be luck, that at 1920x1079 no exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,I found answer, its in my code, I dont exactly understand why,but:

```
//x - screen width
//y - screen height
Bpp = 4; // ?
gs.Position = (x * Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width + y) * Bpp;
```

Comment: This is what I proposed (I've forget the pixelsize), except I think the width should multiplied by y. Bpp is the size of a pixel, remember it is a bytestream and each pixel consists of 4 channels ARGB with each 1 byte.